# Como faço pra exibir imagens baixadas através do URL em um ListView?

Tags: android, listview

O código que tenho até agora é o seguinte:

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.Currency;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.media.Image;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class NoticiasAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    private final Activity activity;
    private final List stocks;
  //  private final Image img;


public NoticiasAdapter(Activity activity, List objects) {
    super(activity, R.layout.noticia_list_item , objects);
    this.activity = activity;
    this.stocks = objects;
   // this.img = url;
}


public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View rowView = convertView;
    StockQuoteView sqView = null;

    if(rowView == null)
    {
        // Get a new instance of the row layout view
        LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.noticia_list_item, null);

        // Hold the view objects in an object,
        // so they don't need to be re-fetched
        sqView = new StockQuoteView();
         //sqView.quote = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.ticker_symbol);
        sqView.ticker = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.ticker_price);
        sqView.img  = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.img);     
        // Cache the view objects in the tag,
        // so they can be re-accessed later
        rowView.setTag(sqView);
    } else {
        sqView = (StockQuoteView) rowView.getTag();
    }

    // Transfer the stock data from the data object
    // to the view objects

    Noticias currentStock = (Noticias) stocks.get(position);
    String imagem3 = currentStock.getImagem();
    sqView.ticker.setText(currentStock.getTitulo());
    sqView.img.setImageURI(currentStock.getBitmapFromURL(imagem3));
  // sqView.quote.setText(currentStock.getDescricao());

    return rowView;
}

protected static class StockQuoteView {
    protected TextView ticker;
    protected TextView quote;
    protected ImageView img;
}

}
```

Código XML:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ticker_price"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="Example application"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textSize="20sp" />



<ImageView 
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:id="@+id/img" />
```

Restante do código:

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;

public class Noticias {

 private  String titulo;
 private  String link;
 private  String comentarios;
 private  String datapublicao;
 private  String criador;
 private  String categoria;
 private  String descricao;
 private String imagem;
 private String nomeimg = "imagem01";
public Noticias(String titulo, String link, String comentarios, String datapublicao ,String criador ,String categoria , String descricao,String imagem) {
    this.titulo = titulo;
    this.link = link;
    this.comentarios = comentarios;
    this.datapublicao = datapublicao;
    this.criador = criador;
    this.categoria = categoria;
    this.descricao= descricao;
    this.imagem = imagem;

}
public void setTitulo(String titulo) {
    this.titulo = titulo;
}
public String getTitulo() {
    return titulo;
}

public void setLink(String link) {
    this.link = link;
}
public String getLink() {
    return link;
}


public void setImagem(String imagem) {
    this.imagem = imagem;
}
public String getImagem() {
    return imagem;
}

public Uri getBitmapFromURL(String url) {
    try {
        URL src = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) src.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        salvando(myBitmap);
        Uri imagemURI = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() +
                "caminho/imagem" + nomeimg );
        return imagemURI;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
private void salvando(Bitmap abmp){

    String file_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() +
            nomeimg;
            File dir = new File(file_path);
            if(!dir.exists())
            dir.mkdirs();
            File file = new File(dir, nomeimg);
            FileOutputStream fOut;
            try {
            fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
            ;
            abmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 85, fOut);
            fOut.flush();
            fOut.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }


}
}
```

Comment: Com esse código que você tem, o que ele faz até agora?

Comment: Antes de tentar mostrar imagens, aparecia os títulos certinho, depois disso a tela fica toda branca.

Comment: Aparece tudo em branco, o nome da imagem estou botando pra ser o url da imagem, não sei se posso fazer isso:public Uri getBitmapFromURL(String url) {
        try {
            URL src = new URL(url);
            
            nomeimg = url;            Se o problema é as imagens pq os títulos tbm não aparecem?